# How to redirect clean url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, href, query-string

I am trying to redirect from javascript autocomplete search bar element.

Search field works perfectly except one thing. 
if i was in **www.example.com/foo** then click a data from search bar. Its redirects me to kinda this pages: **the www.example.com/news/1**

When i try searchbar again. And click products data from search bar. Its redirect me to the **www.example.com/news/products/1**

But i want to **www.example.com/products/1**

**"/news"** must go away.

```
if(window.location.pathname.split("/")[1] === "news"){

window.location.hostname.href ="?tab=" +ui.item.category_id+"&id="+ui.item.id;

}
else
window.location.href ="products?tab=" +ui.item.category_id+"&id="+ui.item.id;
```

> window.location.hostname.href

didn't worked for me? How can i use clean link then add like **"/products/ui.item.id"**

my brief is i can't redirect (href) clean route.

Comment: why are you using `window.location.hostname.href`? I think it should be `window.location.href`

Comment: window.location.href is redirecting /news/products. it should be /products

Comment: i need the clean route. Like hostname.

Comment: use this, `window.location.href ="/products?tab=" +ui.item.category_id+"&id="+ui.item.id`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.location.origin` for this It will give you base url of page.

```
  window.location.href = window.document.location.origin + "products?tab=" + ui.item.category_id + "&id=" + ui.item.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `window.location.pathname` instead.

For example, setting `window.location.pathname = '/products/42'` should cause a redirect to `https://www.example.com/products/42`.